# Correct way to update a contact birthday

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I am trying to update the birthday field of a contact. No matter how I try I always end up with problems, like duplicating the field.

I have tried removing the current birthday and inserting a new one:

```
        // Update value.
        val list = java.util.ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>()

        // Delete current value.
        val updateSelection = """${ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID} = ? AND
                    ${ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE} = ? AND
                    ${CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE} =
                    ${CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY}"""
        val selectionArgs = arrayOf(
                rawId.toString(), CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(updateSelection, selectionArgs)
                .build())

        // Add updated value.
        list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawId)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE, birthdate)
                .withValue(CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE,
                        CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY)
                .build())
```

I have also tried to update the value directly:

```
        list.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(updateSelection, selectionArgs)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawId)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE, birthdate)
                .withValue(CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE,
                        CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY)
                .build())
```

What is the correct way to update a birthday?

Answer (score 0):

Both methods should work, however I would vote for the first approach, as the second one won't work if the raw-contact doesn't already contain a birthday.

I assume the newDelete action didn't find the existing birthday which would lead to creating two birthdays instead of updating the existing one.

You can verify this is indeed the issue, by checking the return value of your `applyBatch` call (`ContentProviderResult[]`), so if the delete is the first action, you can check that `results[0].count` equals 1 (one row deleted).

I believe the issue might be with your selection/args not escaping the `TYPE_BIRTHDAY` value, try this:

```
val updateSelection = """${Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID} = ? AND
                        ${Data.MIMETYPE} = ? AND
                        ${Event.TYPE} = ?"""
val selectionArgs = arrayOf(
                    rawId.toString(), Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY)
```